# How to change the body direction of docs in Docusaurus?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, multilingual, docusaurus

I run my Docusaurus 2 site without a landing page and instead redirect to the first .md file in the sidebar. For doing so, I followed the instruction in the link below and it worked really well:

https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/next/configuration#docs-only-mode

Now, I want to have a multi-language website, English and Persian. The Persian language requires the website to be right-aligned, but I do not know how to do so. I do not use any pages in my project, and I only use a .js file in the pages folder to redirect to the docs.

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to [swizzle](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/cli/#docusaurus-swizzle) the components to handle this. Unfortunately we haven't built a way for translations into Docusaurus 2, but we'll take into account RTL languages when we build it.

Comment: I did not want to change the direction of the components. Actually, I did not have any components. I wanted to just change the direction of .md files in the docs folder. I changed it by setting the direction of the body in custom.css file to "rtl". I'm just wondering that is it a standard way?

Comment: If you want to change the CSS for components, then you'd have to swizzle them. But if you're ok with doing it on a global level, then your way is fine.